# iOS: why can't you have objects in structs?

Tags: ios, struct, automatic-ref-counting

I was wondering why you cannot have objects in structs when using ARC. Whenever I do, I get the error

> ARC forbids objective-c objects in structs

I saw many answers that discuss solutions, but none discuss the underlying reason why it doesn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), it says:

> You cannot use object pointers in C structures.
>
> Rather than using a struct, you can create an Objective-C class to manage the data instead.

If you watch WWDC 2011 video [Introducing Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323), it touches on the point why this is the case on the slide titled *Rule #2/4: No Object Pointers in C Structs* (slide #21), namely that:

> Compiler must know when references come and go
>
> - Pointers must be zero initialized
> - Release when reference goes away

C structs don't satisfy that critiera, which is why they advise using objects instead. You could use `__unsafe_unretained` in conjunction with C structs, but that is, as the name makes obvious, unsafe, and defeats many of the benefits of ARC.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the lifetime of a `struct` is not easy to infer at compile time, and a consequence of this is that if ownership-qualified references were allowed in a struct, the ability to reason about the lifetime of the objects they referred to would be severely complicated at compile time.

The [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions) refer to this complication explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no destructor semantics for C struct. ARC has no clue when to release the object fields in such a struct. Symmetrically, there is neither copy constructor — struct assignment is simply bitwise copy, thus ARC can neither do retain for object fields.